# What are the swirling attachments for on mixers?

Tags: equipment, hand-blender

I have a hand held mixer similar to the one here,

[image: hand held mixer]

The egg beaters are straight forward, but what do people typically use the swirling attachments for? Do they put less air into the mixture??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are dough hooks. They are used to knead yeast dough. They are useful, especially if you are trying to work with higher hydration dough which sticks in hand kneading, but many handheld mixers don't actually have the torque needed to knead dough, so if you need them, make sure to buy a good model which can get the task done.

Comment: What dough has higher hydration? Pasta or risotto dough?

Comment: Pasta dough has very low hydration, and risotto doesn't include dough. Different bread doughs have different hydration, e.g. ciabatta has more than French bread.

Answer (score 2):

I have a low-end Bosch stand mixer with rotating bowl. It has this kind of dough hooks. It takes five minutes at maximum speed to knead the dough properly and it does it's job perfectly too. I always make water roux based breads which is extremely sticky to do by hand.